# numerical precision of cross product in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, precision, cross-product

I am experiencing what I think is weird behavior using cross product in `numpy` with somewhat large values.

E.g., the following seems correct:

```
r = 1e15
a = array([1, 2, 3]) * r;
b = array([-1, 2, 1]) * r;

c = cross(a / norm(a), b / norm(b));

print(dot(c, a))  # outputs 0.0
```

But if we raise the exponent by 1, we get:

```
r = 1e16
a = array([1, 2, 3]) * r;
b = array([-1, 2, 1]) * r;

c = cross(a / norm(a), b / norm(b));

print(dot(c, a))  # outputs 2.0
```

The numbers get even more bizarre for larger values of the exponent.  Does anyone know what is going on here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing round-off error. By default, `array()` returns an object with `dtype=float64`. As you make `r` bigger and bigger, you're running out of mantissa spaces to represent the array products exactly.  Here's a way to test this:

```
def testcross(r, dt):
    a = array([1, 2, 3], dtype=dt)*r
    b = array([-1, 2, 1], dtype=dt)*r
    c = cross(a/norm(a), b/norm(b))
    return dot(c, a)

for rr in logspace(4, 15, 10):
    print "%10.2f %10.2f %g" % (testcross(rr, float32), testcross(rr, float64)
```

With the result:

```
     -0.00       0.00 10000
      0.00      -0.00 166810
      0.00       0.00 2.78256e+06
     -4.00       0.00 4.64159e+07
    -64.00       0.00 7.74264e+08
   1024.00       0.00 1.29155e+10
      0.00       0.00 2.15443e+11
-524288.00       0.00 3.59381e+12
      0.00      -0.02 5.99484e+13
-134217728.00       0.00 1e+15
```

Notice things aren't "perfect" even for `float64` with `r=5.99484e13`. This shows that the precision is starting to fall apart long before you get to `r=1e15`, even for `float64`. As expected, things are much worse with the less-precise `float32`.

Following up on OP's suggestion: the mantissa fields for 32 and 64 bit floating point representation are 24 and 53 bits, respectively (including the implied bit).  Taking `log10([2**24, 2**53])`, we see that this corresponds with about 7 and 16 orders of magnitude respectively. This corresponds with the tabulated errors showing up around `r=4.6e7` for `float32` and `r=1e16` as originally noted. The round-off happens when the dot-product causes the underlying matrix calculation to subtract large numbers, and the differences can't be represented one or the other large number's mantissa.

Comment: Are you sure that addresses the problem?  A 64-bit floating point number should have a mantissa of 11 bits, correct?  That should certainly handle the size of numbers I'm working with.

Comment: Okay--I see it now--it happens in the precision of the multiplication during the dot product.  `a` is large.  The numeric precision of a 64 bit float is 52 bits. 2^52 is just over 10^15, after which the problems with roundoff error seem to escalate.  I think it would be helpful to mention the size of the 64-bit floating point coefficient and mantissa in the answer.  Thanks for the help!